# Complex queries in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Can't quite understand how to perform "complicated" queries in pandas.
Suppose I have a data frame with 3 columns (a, dir, r):

```
    from pandas import DataFrame

    df = DataFrame({
        'a':[10, 15, 20, 30, 8, 14],
        'dir': ['pos', 'abs', 'abs', 'neg', 'abs', 'pos'],
        'r': ['vl', 'pr', 'vl', 'pr', 'vl', 'pr']
    })
```

```
    a   dir  r

    10  pos  vl
    15  abs  pr
    20  abs  vl
    30  neg  pr
    8   abs  vl
    14  pos  pr
```

I want to get all the data, where values in column are > 4, and at the same time dir <> 'abs' and r <> 'pr' (but it's ok if dir=abs and r=vl for example).
So query result should be:

```
    a   dir  r

    10  pos  vl
    20  abs  vl
    30  neg  pr
    8   abs  vl
    14  pos  pr
```

Tried to use that query:

```
df[(df.a > 4) & ((df.dir != 'abs') & (df.r != 'pr'))]
```

But obviously this is not what I want to do, result:

```
    a   dir  r

    10  pos  vl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need instead `&` (and) use `|` (or):

```
print (df[(df.a > 4) & ((df.dir != 'abs') | (df.r != 'pr'))])
    a  dir   r
0  10  pos  vl
2  20  abs  vl
3  30  neg  pr
4   8  abs  vl
5  14  pos  pr
```

Or:

```
print (df.query('a > 4 & dir != "abs" | r != "pr"'))

    a  dir   r
0  10  pos  vl
2  20  abs  vl
3  30  neg  pr
4   8  abs  vl
5  14  pos  pr
```

Similar output is if use `==` with inverting boolean mask by `~`:

```
print (df[(df.a > 4) & ~((df.dir == 'abs') & (df.r == 'pr'))])

    a  dir   r
0  10  pos  vl
2  20  abs  vl
3  30  neg  pr
4   8  abs  vl
5  14  pos  pr
```

Comment: It works on the example I've provided. I will check it with the tool I'm working on, but now it seems very natural. Guess I had wrong understanding of and and or in terms of working with filtering data. Thank you.